# Placement of text in the bottom of cell in latex longtable a table across multiple pages?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have searched a lot about the placement of the text in the bottom of cell in latex table. I am using longtable so that i need the table across two-three pages. But i found somewhere that we cannot use "b" in long table. I have tried using "b", "\raggedbottom" etc. But it din't work for me.

My requirement is, the table should appear across two-three pages. The table has three columns. In the first column the text should be placed in the top (I simply used p{1cm}), and in the middle properly justified text (p{15cm}) and the third column the text should appear at the bottom (Here I tried the most possible ways including b{1cm}). I am not talking about alignment here, I am saying the text should sit at the bottom of the cell.

I have added a snapshot of the requirement (which is done in MS word). But i need it in latex. Kindly help.

[image: Example for the table done using MS word]

Comment: `But i found somewhere that we cannot use "b" in long table.` wherever you found that you were misinformed. cell formatting in longtable just uses the tabular code and all the same options are available.

Comment: Thanks David, but using "b" does not work. I mean it is not placing the text at bottom. Any help there?

Comment: But you need `usepackage{array}` for the `b` specifier to work. However, **`b` does not mean: put the text at the bottom of the cell. There is currently no way to specify that in a tabular, longtable, etc.**

Comment: Yes Peit. I have used the array package. Otherwise it was giving a syntax error.
And Okay. Currently there is no way to that? Thats bad. Well thanks for the information.

Comment: Do you need it for just one cell or a few? Or should it be done in every row?

Comment: Every row last cell. (The third column.) I have around 15 rows which needs to be continued into two-three pages say.

Comment: if the first column was `c`  the middle was `b` and the last was `c` you would get the alignment you show as long as `I am using`  and the enumeration were in different table rows

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried that. But now the third column value appears in the right place but first column value also appears at the bottom which should have been at the top.

Comment: What @DavidCarlisle meant was to put the `4B & I am using latex table` in a separate row, and the rest in the next row.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Thank you. It looks better now. Solved my problem temporarily. 
But one more question. Can't that be done in single row?

Comment: Not automatically. Only if you are willing to do manual tuning. Like adding extra empty lines in the third column or using a `\multirow`.

Comment: normally it's best to not set this as a table at all, the 4B looks like a numbered question so if it was a list that could just be `\item` an the 4B would naturally align  and then the final mark can be something like `\showmark{03}` defined as `\newcommand\showmark{\hspace*{\fill}\rlap{#1}}` which would naturally align as part of the last line of the item.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You guessed right. It is a numbered question. This looks best. But I need it in the table format only. That is the whole "requirement". 
I have created it with your previous solution. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of `longtable` and `tabular` is the same, so I use `tabular` here.

Note that `b` does not mean "place this at the bottom" it means "place the alignment point at the bottom row" so it is the  *middle*  column that wants `b` so the (03) aligns with its bottom row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cb{3cm}c}
4B& I am using&\\
&
zzz

www

qqq
&(03)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```